# React-script Fabricjs jsdom conflict,

Tags: testing, fabricjs, jestjs, jsdom, react-scripts

When I start test in my project below error will happen:

FAIL  src/**tests**/App.js
  ● renders without crashing

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'imageSmoothingEnabled' of null

  at klass._setImageSmoothing (node_modules/fabric/dist/fabric.js:6567:38)
  at klass._initStatic (node_modules/fabric/dist/fabric.js:6348:12)
  at klass.initialize (node_modules/fabric/dist/fabric.js:8611:12)
  at new klass (node_modules/fabric/dist/fabric.js:1961:23)
```

Actually it happens when I create a fabricjs canvas. Is it a conflict between jsdom and fabricjs???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to a commenter in Issue [3567](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues/3567) you need to install fabricjs to make it work. I experienced the problem after upgrading to node-canvas 2 alpha (`npm install canvas@next`).

Either you downgrade node-canvas to 1.x or simply run `npm install fabricjs`. This solved it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I have found the problem. The problem was one of fabric js dependencies. It was [Canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas) . It needs some packages on OS. Depends on your OS.

OS X    :brew install pkg-config cairo libpng jpeg giflib

Ubuntu  :sudo apt-get install libcairo2-dev libjpeg8-dev libpango1.0-dev libgif-dev build-essential g++

Fedora  :sudo yum install cairo cairo-devel cairomm-devel libjpeg-turbo-devel pango pango-devel pangomm pangomm-devel giflib-devel

Solaris     :pkgin install cairo pkg-config xproto renderproto kbproto xextproto

Windows     :Instructions on canvas [wiki](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/wiki/Installation---Windows)

Comment: Looks like I have the same problem as you. but installing those dependencies on mac didn't solve the problem. Can you please share your solution code?